# DOM Exception 8 error when implementing endless scrolling using mustache templates & jquery masonry

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, mustache, jquery-masonry

I am implementing an endless scrolling effect heavily influenced by this tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates?view=asciicast

However, I am doing it slightly differently because I am using Jquery Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html) on the front end.

Anyway, when I implement this as follows:

```
jQuery ->
window.endlessScroll = () ->
    if $('#products_page').length   
        new ProductPager

class ProductPager
constructor: ->
    $(window).scroll(@check)

check: =>
    if @nearBottom()
        $(window).unbind('scroll', @check)
        $.getJSON($('#products_page').data('json-url'), @render)

nearBottom: =>
    $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150

render: (products) =>
    boxes= []
    $container = $('#products_page')
    for product in products
        boxes.push Mustache.render $('#mustache_product').html(), product 
    $container.append(boxes).masonry "appended", boxes
    $(window).scroll(@check)
```

I get the following error (Chrome):

Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

I think the problem lies here:

```
boxes.push Mustache.render $('#mustache_product').html(), product
```

because this wraps each template output in "quotes" i.e.

```
["<div>stuff</div>","<div>more stuff</div>"]
```

rather than:

```
[<div>stuff</div>,<div>more stuff</div>]
```

But I am having a bit of a mental block about what I am doing wrong.... anyone care to help?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by following the example on the Masonry website more closely, which resulted in this:

```
.
.
.
boxMaker.makeBoxes = ->
  boxes = []
  for product in products
    box = document.createElement("div")
    template = Mustache.render $('#mustache_product').html(), product
    box.className = "box"
    box.innerHTML = template
    boxes.push box
  boxes
$boxes = $(boxMaker.makeBoxes())
```